# Merge n arrays A1..An with each Array Ai being a random subset of {1..i}

Tags: arrays, algorithm, runtime, bitarray, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to figure out a way to merge n arrays labeled A1 to An efficiently.

Each array Ai is a subset of `{1..i}`. For example A3 could be {1} or {3} or {1,3}. Note each array is sorted.

For example for `n = 8, A1={}, A2={2}, A3={2,3}, A4={1,4}, A5=A6=A7={}, A8={6}`, merging all of them would give {1,2,3,4,6}.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this **faster than O(n^2),** which is obvious since there are O(n^2) total elements in all of the arrays and we can create an array of size n and try to put each element into a bucket.

Comment: It can't be done in less than the total elements in all of the arrays. Obviously, you need to read each of the elements  in all of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `k` sorted arrays of integers that contain a combined total of `n` items, then you can merge them in O(n log k) time, using O(k) extra space. Here's how it's done:

First, create a type called `pqitem`, that holds an array and the current index into the array. For example:

```
class pqitem
    int[] A;
    int i;
```

Then, create a priority queue (min-heap) to hold `pqitem` instances. The comparison function should compare `A[i]`, so the items in the heap are arranged such that the array with the smallest current item is at the root.

For each of the arrays, create a `pqitem` instance to hold the array. Initialize the `i` field to 0. Insert into the priority queue.

Now, continually remove the lowest item from the heap, output the current value,  increase `i`, and add the item back to the heap if `i < A.length`. That is:

```
myHeap = new heap()
for each array
    item = new pqitem(array, 0)
    myHeap.Add(item)

while (myHeap.count > 0)
    item = myHeap.pop()
    output item.A[item.i]  // output or add to new array, etc.
    ++item.i
    if (item.i < item.A.length)
        myHeap.Add(item)
```

In your case, you want to prevent duplicates. So you modify the merge loop slightly to keep track of the last item output, and prevent outputting duplicate items.

```
// keep track of the previous item
prev = -1  // Initialize to a value that won't appear in the lists
while (myHeap.count > 0)
    item = myHeap.pop()
    // skip duplicates
    if (item.A[item.i] != prev)
        output item.A[item.i]  // output or add to new array, etc.
        prev = item.A[item.i]
    ++item.i
    if (item.i < item.A.length)
        myHeap.Add(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an container which will hold the `k`th item of `i`th array, index `i` and index `k`.

```
public class Node {
    int item, arrIndx, itemIndx;
    public Node(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.item = a;
        this.arrIndx = b;
        this.itemIndx = c;
    }
}
```

Use a minHeap(priority Queue which keep sorted its element in ascending order) to contain the `Node`.

At first for each array, push its first element into the minHeap. How minHeap is holding the first `n` sorted elements.

Now pop the front element from the minHeap one by one which is the smallest among all the items of arrays and put it into output array. During poping any `k`th element of `i`th array, put the `k + 1`th element of `i`th array into queue. This way we are making sure, we are pushing the immediate smallest element of current smallest element.

Continue this process until all arrays elements being pushed and pop-ed from the minHeap.

Sample Java snippet will look like this:

```
public List<Integer> mergekSortedArrays(int[][] arrays) {

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (arrays == null || arrays.length == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    PriorityQueue<Node> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Node>(arrays.length,
        new Comparator<Node>() {
            public int compare(Node lhs, Node rhs) {
                return lhs.item - rhs.item;
            }
        }
    );

    // O(n log n)
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        if (arrays[i].length > 0) {
            minHeap.offer(new Node(arrays[i][0], i, 0));
        }
    }

    Node node;

    // O((N - n)log n)
    while (!minHeap.isEmpty()) {
        node = minHeap.poll();
        result.add(node.item);
        if (node.itemIndx + 1 < arrays[node.arrIndx].length) {
            minHeap.offer(new Node(arrays[node.arrIndx][node.itemIndx + 1], node.arrIndx, node.itemIndx + 1));
        }   
    }

    return result;

}
```

The time complexity is `O(N log n)` where `n` is the number of array and `N` is the number of all elements in those arrays.